# Selecting next list item with down arrow

Tags: javascript

Given a list of divs, I need to be able to use the up and down arrow keys to navigate between items in the list, apply an `.ag-menu-option-active` class to the currently selected item, and on `Enter` key, trigger a click on the currently selected list item.

I'm currently able to iterate over the list of items, but on down arrow, it only logs out the second item in the list. As stated above, the user should be able to move up and down the list and have the active class applied to the currently selected item. When the user hits the `Enter` key, the associated list item should be clicked.

```
let columnMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.ag-menu-option');
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    for (let i = 0; i < columnMenuItems.length; i++) {
      if (columnMenuItems[i].classList.contains('ag-menu-option-active') === true) {
        console.log("MENU OPTION SELECTED: ", columnMenuItems[i + 1])
        columnMenuItems[i].click();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5anhuo0k/23/)**

Comment: you need to add 'ag-menu-option-active' class to the next element and remove it from the previous.
also need to take care of boundry conditions, hope it helps.

Comment: @user6761351 - the `ag-menu-option-active` class is already applied to the next element and removed from the previous element when the user hovers over a list item. One of the things I'm trying to figure out is why the 2nd element in the list always has the active class on arrow down, no matter what.

Comment: its not second item, its the first one , you are printing the second  columnMenuItems[i + 1]

Comment: adding code for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
if(columnMenuItems[i+1] !== undefined){
    //add class to next 
    columnMenuItems[i+1].className= "ag-menu-option ag-menu-option-active"

    columnMenuItems[i].className= "ag-menu-option"
}
```

you can write some other logic to add and remove class but this should work for arrow down.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the +/- when you are calling .click() method;
Also to prevent the undefined error you should add columnMenuItems-1 in first for loop.

Code should look like this -

```
if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    for (let i = 0; i < columnMenuItems.length-1; i++) {
      if (columnMenuItems[i].classList.contains('ag-menu-option-active') === true) {
        console.log("MENU OPTION SELECTED: ", columnMenuItems[i + 1]);
        columnMenuItems[i].classList.remove('ag-menu-option-active');
        columnMenuItems[i + 1].click();
        columnMenuItems[i+1].classList.add('ag-menu-option-active');
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    for (let i = columnMenuItems.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      //console.log("MENU OPTIONS: ", columnMenuItems[i]);
      if (columnMenuItems[i].classList.contains('ag-menu-option-active') === true) {
        columnMenuItems[i].classList.remove('ag-menu-option-active');
        //if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          columnMenuItems[i - 1].click();
        columnMenuItems[i-1].classList.add('ag-menu-option-active');
        //}
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Test it [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5anhuo0k/55/)